# Why click don't work on some buttons in selenium?

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, xpath, web-scraping, click

I have used click process in selenium with python more and more correctly. But, I don't know why it don't work correctly now in my code:

```
number=driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="ui-id-4"]""")
number.click()
```

The HTML code of that is similar to:

```
<div id="ui-id-4" tabindex="-1" role="option" class="ui-menu-item-wrapper ui-state-active">200</div>
```

In fact, I previously succeed to click on "resultsPerPage-button" and now I want to select 200 per page button between 20,50,100 and 200. I used selenium in my code.
What should I do?

Comment: id is dynamic ?

Comment: //*[text()="200"] try this xpath

Comment: just this?:
//*[text()="200"]

Comment: yeah given xpath ll locate 200

Comment: It doesn't work.

Comment: try this :-  //*[@role="option" and text()="200"]

Comment: It doesn't work too. Still, do you think my problems come from Xpath?

Comment: I can solve it. My solution has been presented in Answer situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used id instead XPath and it worked well. Also, use of delay was essential for this code.

```
import time
numberl=driver.find_element_by_id("ui-id-4")
numberl.click()
time.sleep(8)
```